# Why does list( tuple ).append('a') not work?

Tags: python

I find that this works :

```
a = list(('i', 'am'))
a.append('a')
a

['i', 'am', 'a']
```

but not this :

```
b = list(('i','am')).append('a')
b
```

Comment: list.append modifies the list and returns None.

Comment: If you want to do it in a single line, you can e.g. do `b = [*tuple, a]`

Comment: Or `list((tuple)) + [a]`

Answer (score 3):

`b` isn't assigned the list; it is assigned the result of the `append` method, which is `None`.

Put another way, `b = list(('i','am')).append('a')` is not interpreted as

```
(b = list(('i','am'))).append('a')
```

---

Starting in Python 3.8, you *could* write

```
(b := list(('i', 'am'))).append('a')
```

using the assignment expression operator `:=` to get the desired effect, but I feel confident in claiming that would be considered poor style.